# Not-null property references a transient value transient instance must be saved before current operation

Tags: java, hibernate

i am having the table `product` in that table one of the foreign key `dimension_id`. so while writing my test case in service layer it shows the error.
 this is my test case

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    private ProductBO getProductBO() {
        SellerBO sellerBO = getSellerBO();
        ProductBO productBO = new ProductBO();
        productBO.setCategoryId(1);
        productBO.setDateAvailable("20/00/0000");
        productBO.setImage("a15cb5e");
        productBO.setLocation("for getting product details");
        productBO.setMinimum(26.00);
        productBO.setModel("service");
        productBO.setPoints(5);
        productBO.setPrice(12.2f);
        productBO.setQuantity("2");
        productBO.setSellerBO(sellerBO);
        productBO.setShipping(2);
        productBO.setSku("aqaqaq");
        productBO.setSortOrder("aes");
        productBO.setStatus(1);
        productBO.setStockStatusId("20");
        productBO.setProductName("Micromax");
        productBO.setSubtract(20.0001);
        productBO.setUpc("asd");
        productBO.setViewed(2);
        productBO.setWeight("25");
        productBO.setWeightClassBO(getWeightClassBO(productBO));
        productBO.setDimensionBO(getDimension());
        return productBO;
    }


public DimensionBO getDimension() {
        DimensionBO dimensionBO = new DimensionBO();
        dimensionBO.setHeight(12);
        dimensionBO.setLength(23);
        dimensionBO.setWidth(14);
        dimensionBO.setLengthClassBO(getLengthClass());
        try {
            manageDimensionServiceImpl.addDimension(dimensionBO);
        } catch (CrafartServiceException csExp) {
            csExp.printStackTrace();
            Assert.fail();
        }

        return dimensionBO;

    }
```

this is my  dimensionimpl

```
@Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void addDimension(DimensionBO dimensionBO) throws CrafartServiceException {

        DimensionDO dimensionDO = beanMapper.mapDimensionBOToDO(dimensionBO, new DimensionDO(), beanMapper.mapLengthClassBOToDO(dimensionBO.getLengthCassBO(), new LengthClassDO()));
        try {

            dimensionDAOImpl.addDimension(dimensionDO);
            dimensionBO.setDimensionId(dimensionBO.getDimensionId());
            //LengthClassDO lengthClassDO = lengthClassDAOImpl.getLengthClass(dimensionBO.getLengthCassBO().getLengthClassId());
            //dimensionDO.setLengthClassDO(lengthClassDO);
        } catch (CrafartDataException e) {
            throw new CrafartServiceException("Error while adding dimension", e);

        }

    }
```

this is my dimensionDAOimpl

```
@Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void addDimension(DimensionDO dimensionDO) throws CrafartDataException {
        try {
            Session session = this.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
            session.persist(dimensionDO);
        } catch (HibernateException hExp) {
            throw new CrafartDataException("DB Error while adding dimension details in table", hExp);
        }
    }

}
```

DO to BO mapping

```
public DimensionBO mapDimensionDOTOBO(DimensionDO dimensionDO,DimensionBO dimensionBO,LengthClassBO lengthClassBO) {
        dimensionBO.setDimensionId(dimensionBO.getDimensionId());
        dimensionBO.setHeight(dimensionBO.getHeight());
        dimensionBO.setLength(dimensionBO.getLength());
        dimensionBO.setWidth(dimensionBO.getWidth());
        dimensionBO.setLengthClassBO(lengthClassBO);
        return dimensionBO;
    }
```

BO to DO mapping

```
public DimensionDO mapDimensionBOToDO(DimensionBO dimensionBO, DimensionDO dimensionDO ,LengthClassDO lengthClassDO)  {
        dimensionDO.setDimensionId(dimensionDO.getDimensionId());
        dimensionDO.setHeight(dimensionDO.getHeight());
        dimensionDO.setLength(dimensionDO.getLength());
        dimensionDO.setWidth(dimensionDO.getWidth());
        dimensionDO.setLengthClassDO(lengthClassDO);

        return dimensionDO;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception that you are getting `Not-null property references a transient value transient instance must be saved before current operation` means that while you are persisting `dimensionDO` object, there is a relation of thi object that references a non-persisted (*that is a transient*) object, and thus it can not manage foreign key.

Your code doesn't show where it can be this relation. Maybe when you map from `dimensioBO` to `dimensionDO` you create a new instance that you have to persist before.

On the other hand, in `productBO` you have two reference to new instances, one for `sellerBO` and one for `dimensionBO`. But you don't show code for product persistence ...

Comment: i will add my dimensionBO to dimensionDO can u tell where i have to change

Comment: It seems that the only reference that `dimensionDO` has, is `LengthClassDO`. Is this object persisted before? If this object it is not persisted before you have three options, persist it before, load a persisted entitiy or configure cascade to trigger `LengthClassDO` persistence when invoked `dimensionDO` persistence.